# 1.5 + 1.5 > 3 : difficulties aligning columns in tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I made 4-column table and a separate 2-column table.  I thought if the columns were twice the size they should align but they don't.  What is the problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.25in}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3in}|p{3in}|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're forgetting the `\tabcolsep` space at either side of a table column. So the first table is 6in plus 8`\tabcolsep` wide, whereas the second is just 6in plus 4`\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.25in}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3in+2\tabcolsep}|p{3in+2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You need to add `2\tabcolsep` to each of the column in the second table.

[image]

If you want that the cells are 1.5in or 3in wide including the padding, you can remove it from the stated width:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{p{1.5in-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.25in}

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{3in-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you shouldn't set `\tabcolsep` to zero, or the cell text will be right next to the vertical rules.

Answer (score 3):

There is an inherent spacing between column elements namely `\tabcolsep`. When you reset them (via`@{}` everywhere) you get

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}|@{}p{1.5in}@{}|@{}p{1.5in}@{}|@{}p{1.5in}@{}|@{}p{1.5in}@{}|@{}}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.25in}

\begin{tabular}{@{}|@{}p{3in}@{}|@{}p{3in}@{}|@{}}
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is nonsense instead you can add the mismatch to the latter as egreg did in his answer as I was casually typing my amazing answer.